# Datatable AJAX, JSON & JQUERY - net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I'm using the Datatables library to build an auto-refreshing table from a JSON feed. Which is working, however it throws this error every time data in the table changes:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

The table does update correctly, it just throws a pop-up error every time it does. I'm completely new the Javascript/JQUERY so I'm clutching at straws trying to resolve it.

Here's my custom code for the initial load and refresh:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "http:xxx.com/datatables/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt"
} );

    setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }, 1000 );

} );
```

Is there anyway I can stop the error popping-up? If it wasn't for the pop-up, the table does what it is supposed to do.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED - I was pulling the table onto the page with an iframe instead of natively building the table - This was causing the headers to be messed up.